# How to create treePanel by using recursive methodology in EXT.NET?

Tags: c#, ext.net, treepanel

I am new at Ext.net.As many of you know,there are few resources for Ext.net.I have a list get from db by using connect by prior.I want to load list to tree basicly.But I dont want to see root node of tree.How can load tree by using recursive method.

Could you please give example how tree is loaded.

Comment: Can you write a recursive function? Like a factorial one?

Comment: Of course,i can write recursive func? But I don't know how to combine with ex.net treepanel.

Comment: It work very well with recursive call.